# c# byte array to image conversation for earlier frameworks?(win CE)

Tags: c#, image, windows-ce, memorystream

I want to convert byte array to image as I say on title and 
I tried this,

```
byte[] data = (byte[]) dt.Rows[0]["IMAGE"];
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

but I m working on framework 3.5 compact for Win CE OS. and it gives error for 
   "Image.FromStream"
Compiler says;

Error   2   'System.Drawing.Bitmap' does not contain a definition for 'FromStream'  C:\Users....\Fonksiyonlar.cs   93  75  Terminal

Can you offer any other way to do this?

Comment: What image format are you using?

Comment: bmp or jpeg. it's comming from SQL image column

Comment: The error message is weird - are you sure that's exactly what it says? Do you perhaps have a member named `Image` in your class?

Comment: Ok, BMP and JPEG are supported by Bitmap constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Windows CE here, but I believe you can try:

```
pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(ms);
```

Comment: As per MSDN, this is `Supported by the .NET Compact Framework.`, so it should work.

Comment: Yeah according to MSDN here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw(v=vs.90).aspx